# How can i use data from .XML file for android App?

Tags: android, xml, database, sdk

i am developing an android app of a Novel. All data i have is in .xml format just as Chapter id, and then  line ids. I want to add a feature in app that is to search any chapter's any line exactly. Will that XML file be helpful in it ? Moreover can i use XML as backend data holder for app but then what script i will use to import data respectively ?

```
<chapter index="1" name="intro">
  <line index="1" text="lorus depegumasd" />
  <line index="2" text="as ilatuyn masdu" />
  <line index="3" text="its aduw adeioyan" />
</chapter>
<chapter index="2" name="preface">
  <line index="1" text="lorus depegumasd" />
  <line index="2" text="as ilatuyn masdu" />
  <line index="3" text="its aduw adeioyan" />
</chapter>
```

its just like as i mentioned above. Kindly help me about the script to be used to add feature such that in android app user may load any line of any chapter or a given range like from line 3 to 6 of chapter 7

regards,
--shumail

Comment: you need to parse XML source and you can use JSON to for interacting with source from android app. See this for details: [enter link description here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)

Answer (score 1):

IBM has an excellent tutorial on working with XML in Android which presents several options on how to parse an XML source. They provide sample code as well as an explanation of which methods would be most useful in which situations. Have a look here: [Working with XML on Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)